# Is every linear independent set which has dense span in Hilbert space a Schauder basis?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

We know that for general separable Banach space, not every linear independent set which is dense is a Schauder basis. For separable Hilbert space, is every linear independent set(not necessary orthogonal) that is dense a Schauder basis of the Hilbert space?

My guess is yes, because every linear independent set can be made orthogonal by the Gram-Schmidt procedure, but I am not sure about the situation before the procedure.

**Edit**

I made a terrible mistake, what I intend to ask is if the span of linear independent set is dense, is the set a Schauder basis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is negative. A dense set $D$ in a Hilbert or Banach space $X$ can never be a Schauder basis, because the representation is not unique. For each $F \subset D$ finite and $x \in x$, we can write $x$ as a sum of series of elements from $D_0=D \setminus F$. Choose $d_1 \in D_0$ such that
$\|x-d_1\|<1/2$. If $d_1,\ldots,d_{k-1} \in D_0$ have been chosen, then select
$d_k \in D_0$ so that $\|x-\sum_{j=1}^k d_j\|<2^{-k}$. Then
$$d=\sum_{k=1}^\infty d_k \,.$$

**A variant** of the question (which is often asked) is:

``For separable Hilbert space $H$, does every linearly independent set(not necessary orthogonal) that has a  dense span, necessarily contain a subsequence that is a Schauder basis of $H$?''

The answer is still negative, but for a different reason. The sequence of powers $1,x,x^2,\ldots$ has a dense span in $L^2[-1,1]$. But no subsequence of the powers can be a Schauder basis,
because if $f$ in $L^2[-1,1]$ is not real analytic, it is not the sum in $L^2$ of a power series. Indeed, power series converge uniformly inside their radius of convergence, and outside it the summands do not tend to zero in L^2.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis

Comment: I made a terrible mistake, what I intend to ask is if the span of linear independent set is dense, is the set a Schauder basis. But I guess from the answer you provided, I think the answer is negative.

Comment: Right, I thought you might have intended to ask that, so I included an answer for this variant. Do you know how to accept an answer?

Comment: Just want to point out even if $f$ is not real analytic, it could get a sequence of real analytic functions converging to it in $L^2$ sense. The convergence need not be pointwise.

Comment: This post seems to say when it will happen, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4329949/conditions-for-a-linearly-independent-sequence-with-dense-linear-span-to-be-a-sc