# projection operator in Hilbert space and Schauder basis

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $\{b_{i}\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a linear independent set that has a dense span. Let $B_{n}=span(b_{i}, i\leq n)$. Define $P_{n}:H\rightarrow B_{n}$ be a linear operator, by $P_{n}x=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\langle b_{i},x\rangle b_{i}$.

According to Wikipedia, if there exists a closed subspace $V$ such that $H=B_{n}\oplus V$, then $P_{n}$ is bounded. In this case, if we define $V=B_{n}^{\perp}$, this must a closed subspace. So $P_{n}$ is bounded.

Now $\sup_{n}||P_{n}x||<\infty$ for all $x\in H$, because $\sup_{n}||P_{n}x||\leq||x||$. By uniform boundedness principle, $P_{n}$ is uniformly bounded. So for $x=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}b_{i}$, $K||x||\geq||P_{m}x||$ for $m\leq n$, where $K$ can be chosen as the uniform bound, with its existence guaranteed by uniform boundedness principle.

But this means $b_{i}$ is a Schauder basis, which implies every linear independent set with dense span is a Schauder basis in $H$, which is not true(see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4486016/is-every-linear-independent-set-which-has-dense-span-in-hilbert-space-a-schauder)). So what's wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: Your $P_n$'s are not projections even if you replace $b_i$ with $\dfrac{b_i}{\lVert b_i \rVert^2}$, which means $\lVert P_n x \rVert \le \lVert x \rVert$ does not hold in general.

Comment: Is it because $b_{i}$ is not orthogonal, so even replace with $\frac{b_{i}}{||b_{i}||^{2}}$, $P_{n}$ are not a projections?

Comment: Yes. You can see this by choosing $x=b_1=(1,0,0, \dotsc)$ and $b_2=(\cos \theta, \sin \theta,0, \dotsc)$ for sufficiently small $\theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$ and let $b_k=\sum_{j=1}^ke_k$. Then $\{b_k\}$ is linearly independent with dense range, and
$$
P_ne_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\langle e_n,b_k\rangle\,b_k=b_n=\sum_{k=1}^ne_k,
$$
so $\|P_ne_n\|=\sqrt n\,\|e_n\|$. The norm of $P_n$ is even bigger, since
$$
P_ne_1=\sum_{k=1}^n\langle e_1,b_k\rangle\,b_k=\sum_{k=1}^nb_k=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^ke_j=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=j}^ne_j=\sum_{j=1}^n(n-j+1)e_j,
$$
so
$$
\|P_ne_1\|=\sqrt{\frac{3n^3+2n^2+n}{6}}\,\|e_1\|.
$$
Besides this, the $P_n$ are not idempotents, as can also be seen from the above example. For instance
$$
P_n^2e_n=\sum_{k=1}^nP_ne_k=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\langle e_k,b_j\rangle\,b_j=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=k+1}^n\sum_{h=1}^je_h\ne P_ne_n.
$$