Schauder bases and embeddings in Hilbert spaces
I would like to know whether continously and densely embedded orthonormal bases are always Schauder bases of the larger space. More precisely:
Let $(H, \langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle_H)$ and $(\tilde{H}, \langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle_{\tilde{H}})$ be separable Hilbert spaces which admit a continuos and dense embedding $\iota: H \to \tilde{H}$. If $(h_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an orthonormal basis in $H$, is $(\iota(h_n))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a Schauder basis in $\tilde{ H}$? Intuitively I would think yes, but I don't know how I could prove this. Maybe some Gram-Schmidt type argument? I have very little experience in working with Schauder bases to be honest.
The application I specifically care about is if $H$ is a closed left-shift invariant subspace of $L^2(0,\infty;X)$, where $X$ is some separable Hilbert space, and $\tilde{H}$ is the closure of $H$ in the extraploation space $H^{-1}(0,\infty;X)=(H^1_0(0,\infty;X))^\ast$. My basis elements $(h_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are usually not in the Sobolev space $H^1(0,\infty;X)$, so I can't really use duality I guess.

The post https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4329949/700025 states a necessary and sufficient conditon for $(h_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ to be a Schauder basis. I am not sure how to check this, so it doesn't immediately help but seems relevant enough to link anyway.

I’m not entirely sure, but this seems like a counterexample: Let $H = l^2$ and $(h_n)$ be the standard ONB. Let $\tilde{H} = L^2([0, 1])$. Let $\iota: H \to \tilde{H}$ be defined by $\iota((a_n)) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n} x^{n-1}$.

@DavidGao thanks for your comment. Do you habe a reference/explanation as to why the monomials are not a Schauder basis in $L^2$? I know they are the standard examples for not being a Riesz basis in $L^2$ and for not being Schauder in in the continuous functions, but not seen before that they are not Schauder in $L^2$.

I’m not sure. I’m under the impression that they do not form a Schauder basis in $L^2$ but I don’t know a proof either, which was why I didn’t write an answer but just a comment. I just realized, however, that the same method can be applied to a sequence which I know for sure is not a Schauder basis to give a counterexample. I’ll write it as an answer shortly.

Let $\tilde{H} = l^2$. Define,
$$f_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}e_k \in \tilde{H}$$
We have the following lemmas:
Lemma 1: $\text{span}\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is dense in $\tilde{H}$.
Proof: It is easy to check that $\text{span}\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is the space of all finitely supported sequences, which is dense in $l^2$. $\square$
Lemma 2: If $\sum_n a_nf_n = 0$, then $a_n = 0$ for all $n$.
Proof: Taking inner products with $e_k$, we have,
$$\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n = 0$$
As this holds for all $k$, it is not hard to see $a_n = 0$ for all $n$. $\square$
Lemma 3: $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not a Schauder basis of $H$.
Proof: It suffices to show $\sum_k \frac{1}{k} e_k$ cannot be written as an infinite linear combination of $f_n$. Indeed, assume to the contrary that $\sum_k \frac{1}{k}e_k = \sum_n a_nf_n$, then again by taking inner products with $e_k$,
$$\frac{1}{k} = \frac{1}{k}\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n \Rightarrow \sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n = 1$$
As this holds for all $k$, we may check that $a_n = 0$ for all $n$, which is a contradiction. $\square$
Now let $g_n = \frac{f_n}{\|f_n\|}$. Then, let $H = l^2$ and $\iota: H \to \tilde{H}$ be defined by,
$$\iota((a_n)) = \sum_n \frac{a_n}{n}g_n$$
Note that this is well-defined. Indeed, as $(a_n) \in l^2$, $(\frac{a_n}{n}) \in l^1$, so as $\|g_n\| = 1$, we have $\sum_n \frac{a_n}{n}g_n$ converges absolutely. Furthermore,
$$\|\sum_n \frac{a_n}{n}g_n\| \leq \sum_n |\frac{a_n}{n}| \leq \|(\frac{1}{n})\|_{l^2}\|(a_n)\|_{l^2}$$
So $\iota$ is bounded. By Lemmas 1 and 2, it is thus a continuous and dense embedding. But $(\iota(e_n)) = (g_n)$ is not a Schauder basis, as $(g_n)$ is simply the normalization of $(f_n)$, which is not a Schauder basis per Lemma 3.
